# MongoDB $aggregate $push operation in Java

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I have mongo aggregate query as below:

```
{
$group: {
     _id: {applicationNumber: "$applicationNumber"},
     recordTypes: { $push: "$allRecords.coreRecord.recordType"}
    }
}
```

I need to write its respective java code in aggregation.
I tried as below, but got exception **Invalid reference allRecords.coreRecord.recordType**

```
Aggregation.group("applicationNumber").push("allRecords.coreRecord.recordType").as("recordTypes);
```

Comment: Have you tried using `$`: `.group("$applicationNumber").push("$allRecords.coreRecord.recordType")` ?